# Multiple instances of custom directive failing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Plnkr link -- [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/zKRifmcg9fOjtYiFA28E?p=preview)

In the above plnkr, I have created the a custom directive called dynamic-table which is supposed to take in two JSON objects as attributes and display a table generated using these two JSONs.

Below is the code in index.html where I have created two instances of the dynamic-table directive -

```
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="initializeFunction()">
      <dynamic-table tablestructure="personDetailsObject" tabledata="personDetailsData"></dynamic-table>
      <dynamic-table tablestructure="productTableStructure" tabledata="productTableData"></dynamic-table>
    </div>
  </body>
```

The rendered HTML is not always consistent and the first table does not load. Looks like it is scope issue due to which there are some variables that are getting shared across the instances and creating issue, but I am not able to figure out a fix for it.

Also I am using a javascript library from arboreal.js which is not angular. Using objects created out of this library in my link function. Not sure whether this could create this issue.

Note - The directive works fine if there is only one instance of it.

Please provide a solution for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there's a couple of things you're not considering here. In your plunker you have this:

```
scope.$watch('tablestructure', function(newTablestructure){
    generateTheDataStructure(newTablestructure);
});

generateTheDataStructure = function(arguments) {...etc}
```

Since directives execute at priority `0`, hence before controllers, the initial value of `newTableStructure` is an empty object, because of the initial declaration in the controller, however the watch is going to execute still the first time, and then it will change to whatever your `$http` returns. `scope.$watch` will consider this first change, so `generateTheDataStructure` will be executed, but the "version" of the `generateTheDataStructure` function executed in your first directive might not necessarily be the same function you declarad right below the watch, cause since the second instance of the directive is also being executed, and the function is a global assignment, it might be already available, so perhaps you're losing reference of the scope in which the function is being called, I can't tell really the X's and O's of what is happening with this global function, but that's what breaking your directive.

By the time you call the `generateTheDataStructure` inside the watch in the second directive, the function already exists, so your table renders fine.

In order to solve this, you should either assing your function inside the lexical scope of your `link` function like this:

```
var generateTheDataStructure = function(arguments) {...etc}
```

or declare it instead

```
function generateTheDataStructure(arguments) {...etc}
```

Since function declaration is hoisted, it's safer the second way. I would love to have a little more knowledge of the `$digest` cycle in order to really understand what's happening here, but that should fix your directive.

Conclusion:
**Don't use global variables.**